# Having trouble redirecting old product sites and categories to new pages

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently upgraded a shopsystem to prestashop and imported the previous products (~1200), and I managed to keep the old `category_id` and `product_id`. I'm trying to set up those 2 rules to redirect all my old incoming links to the new page, however for some reason they always end up on the 404 page instead. 
So my old link was

```
detail.php?artikel_id=123
```

and now this product became

```
product.php?id_product=123
```

here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ /prestashop/webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/prestashop/index\.php?artikeltyp=([0-9]+)$ /prestashop/category.php?id_category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/index\.php?artikeltyp=([0-9]+)$ /prestashop/category.php?id_category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/prestashop/detail\.php?artikel_id=([0-9]+)$ /prestashop/product.php?id_product=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/detail\.php?artikel_id=([0-9]+)$ /prestashop/product.php?id_product=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /prestashop/404.php
```

Note that this is my test installation at my laptop, and the new shop is currently set up under `"http://localhost/prestashop/"`. I tried it with and without the `/prestashop/` in the rules, no effect. My .htaccess is in `http://localhost/prestashop/.htaccess`.

Any idea of what I do wrong here? Did I escape it correct? How can I find out where it actually tries to redirect to me before i get the 404?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common mistake that a lot of people do is trying to match whole URL including query string. The reality is: **when matching URL, the pattern get applied to path part of it and query string has to be matched separately**.

In other words -- `RewriteRule` cannot be used to match query string directly -- only with help of `RewriteCond`.

---

Considering the aforementioned the rule to redirect `detail.php?artikel_id=123` to `product.php?id_product=123` should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?artikel_id=(\d+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^detail\.php$ /prestashop/product.php?id_product=%2 [R=301,L]
```

This will do 301 Permanent Redirect -- it will tell search engine and ordinary user that from now on this new URL should be used instead of old one (plus helping with duplicate content issue from search engine point of view when the same content is accessible by 2 different URLs: old one and new one).

If you do not want 301 redirect for some reason, then just remove `R=301,` part.

Considering that this .htaccess is located in `/prestashop/` folder, the rule may need some slight tweaking (like providing full URL in RewriteRule target, e.g. `RewriteRule ^detail\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/prestashop/product.php?id_product=%2 [R=301,L]`)

Comment: Thank you good sir! It worked after some minor adjustments ( id_product=%2 must be id_product=%1 ).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "/prestashop" from your rewrite rules but add

```
RewriteBase /prestashop
```

just after:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Also, you can read about RewriteBase here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase